# NAT to Guest VM not working

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

Port forwarding to my guest VM (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) from my Host system (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)
works fine.

**Solution found. More details at the end.**

I am quite new to Linux and this routing problem is too much 4 me :-(.
I tried several HowTos, but my connection attempts ar getting refused.
I have to use NAT on my host system, because the system is hosted and I can't use the bridge mode and get an IP from the router/external DHCP-Server

`iptables-save -t nat`

returns

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [56:4139]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.38:443
-A PREROUTING -d <<PUBLIC_IP_FROM_ISP>>/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "KVM 443 port forwarding to guest" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.38:443
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

If I check the open ports on my host system with nmap (nmap -sT -p- 
), I get the following

```
Not shown: 65529 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
4330/tcp  open  dey-sapi
9090/tcp  open  zeus-admin
44321/tcp open  pmcd
44322/tcp open  pmcdproxy
44323/tcp open  pmwebapi
```

Same request on the host against my Guest VM returns all open ports I need.

```
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

My goal was to set up an individual VM for our Web solutions in order to be able to migrate the system easily to another server or create just a simple snapshot before we do/test main updates.

I used the default nat bridge with IP-reservation for my guestVM MAC-Address, which is set up during initial KVM setup.

Thank You all for Your help an support.

**Update 01 extra iptables data:**

more iptables data:

```
sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 1 packets, 52 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  508137 59430407 LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  508088 59399010 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  508088 59399010 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      81     5972 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      81     5972 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      81     5972 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      81     5972 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4275   385908 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.38       tcp dpt:443
    6273 11957555 LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    6273 11957555 LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    4949   863499 LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 80 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  507394 26565600 LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  507370 26534860 ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  507370 26534860 ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   66302  4131995 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   66302  4131995 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   66302  4131995 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   66302  4131995 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1324 11094056 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4949   863499 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      28     2187 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
     109    35546 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
       1       60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
     109    36832 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
       1       60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:68

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       1       52 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  438270 21925333 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   69721 37466909 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       3      120 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       3      120 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
      14      728 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
      14      728 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  438270 21925333 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2798   477532 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   66222  4126075 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       3      120 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      14      728 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
       0        0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   65549  3932940 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
     711   195455 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      13      676 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9090
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:9090
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And one more as requested by
Doug Smythies

```
sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 244 packets, 45721 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1006    60836 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:192.168.122.38:443
       0        0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <<PublicIP>>        tcp dpt:443 /* 443 port forwarding */ to:192.168.122.38:443

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  286599 17352173 LIBVIRT_PRT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LIBVIRT_PRT (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       1       40 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255
       5      300 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
      92     6992 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
       0        0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

**Update 02 qemu file for portforwarding if the specified guest os is beeing started**

/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu

```
#!/bin/bash

# IMPORTANT: Change the "VM NAME" string to match your actual VM Name.
# In order to create rules to other VMs, just duplicate the below block and configure
# it accordingly.
if [ "${1}" = "Ubuntu_NextCloud" ]; then

   # Update the following variables to fit your setup
   GUEST_IP=192.168.122.38
   GUEST_PORT1=8080
   HOST_PORT1=80
   GUEST_PORT2=4433
   HOST_PORT2=443

   if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT1 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT1
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT2 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT2 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT2


   fi
   if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT1 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT1
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT2 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT2 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT2

   fi
fi
```

I needed to improve my qemu-hook script.
It was missing the interface-option for my nic to the internet (-i ens6 in my case) so all traffic from all interfaces have been rerouted to the VM.

```
if [ "${1}" = "<<YOUR_VMNAME>>" ]; then

   # Update the following variables to fit your setup
   GUEST_IP=192.168.122.XXX
   GUEST_PORT1=80
   HOST_PORT1=80
   GUEST_PORT2=443
   HOST_PORT2=443

   if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6  --dport $HOST_PORT1 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT1
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT2 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6 --dport $HOST_PORT2 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT2


   fi
   if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6 --dport $HOST_PORT1 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT1
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT2 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6 --dport $HOST_PORT2 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT2

   fi
fi
```

I hope that this solution saves some time for others :-).

Comment: We also need to see the rest of iptables rules, the non-nat ones. Myself, I'd like to see the outputs for `sudo iptables -xvnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL`, but other readers like the format you are using. While it shouldn't make any difference, for your application I prefer to use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I updated the question details with the requested iptables data. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, looking only at port 443. I do not know if you can scan from the host and invoke port forwarding at the same time. Try accessing port 443 from an external computer. Your 2nd PREROUTING rule will never be hit because the 1st rule will be hit first. I would specify the incoming NIC for your PREROUTING rule. If troubles continue, watch the packet counters while trying to connect to port 443. Add tcpdump monitoring and iptables logging rules for debugging. I would use `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <<ext_nic>> -j SNAT --to <<PublicIP>>`

Comment: Thanks will try it. Strange it's a vanilla ubuntu setup with a kvm an not much more on it. Would not have expected such troubles... . But we do love challenges, right? ;-)

Comment: Did a portscan on my publich IP and it tells me that 443 is open. But I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. 
Same with curl from host console against public IP. If I curl 192.168.122.38:443 I get the webserver response website. So must be something on the host system. Could there be another service on the host to block the port? I have one running for cockpit on port 9090, but not on 443.

Comment: Update I can now access my guest VM, if I use a QEMU-file in /etc/libvirts/hooks.
The problem is, that, if I set the portforwarding for port 80 and 443 to the guest, then the guest is unable to do ubuntu updates, certbot stuff,...
So for now, I remove the qemu file and restart guest + network then I can update the guest and after the update I restore the qemu file and restart the guest.
I updated my description with the content of the qemu-file.
I have no Idea, how I can tweak the qemu-file for allowing the ports and be able to update the guest os.

Comment: @DougSmythies
I found the solution ;-). I needed to add the interface to my qemu-hook-script. I updated my decription.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to improve my qemu-hook script. It was missing the interface-option for my nic to the internet (-i ens6 in my case) so all traffic from all interfaces have been rerouted to the VM.

```
if [ "${1}" = "<<YOUR_VMNAME>>" ]; then

   # Update the following variables to fit your setup
   GUEST_IP=192.168.122.XXX
   GUEST_PORT1=80
   HOST_PORT1=80
   GUEST_PORT2=443
   HOST_PORT2=443

   if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6  --dport $HOST_PORT1 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT1
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT2 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6 --dport $HOST_PORT2 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT2


   fi
   if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6 --dport $HOST_PORT1 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT1
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -p tcp  -i ens6 -d $GUEST_IP --dport $GUEST_PORT2 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp  -i ens6 --dport $HOST_PORT2 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT2

   fi
fi
```

I hope that this solution saves some time for others :-).